# Assert with regsvr32 in map_ss.cpp

Tags: assert, regsvr32

I have a serious problem I do not know how to fix it. When registering a "dll", regsvr32 returns a strange error and I do not know how to fix it. Can you think any idea how to track it?

[image]

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Finally, I have solved the problem. 
I had 2 static variables, one (A) within the constructor's other (B). VS internally initialized (created in memory) A before B, and of course aborted. 
The most curious is the error not appears in runtime, it appears when I try to register it with regsvr32. why?